# cakephp 3 controller reference in component

Tags: php, cakephp, plugins, cakephp-3.0

I have a little problem inside my component plugin written for cakephp 3

I would like to redirect to another page but It seems that I can't use correctly my controller reference.
When I redirect to another page, starts a long waiting time like It doesn't find the page but no error.

Inside my component I have write something like this:

```
namespace UserPermissions\Controller\Component;

use Cake\Controller\Component;
use Cake\Controller\ComponentRegistry;
use Cake\Datasource\ConnectionManager;
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;
use Cake\Controller\Component\FlashComponent;

class UserPermissionsComponent extends Component {
     public $controller = null;

     public function initialize(array $config)
     {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->controller = $this->_registry->getController();
        $this->session = $this->controller->request->session();
     }

     public function redirect () {
          return $this->controller->redirect(
            ['controller' => 'example2', 'action' => 'index']
         );
     }
}
```

redirect method seems that doesn't work

What is the correct way to reference a controller?

Thanks

Comment: How are you calling redirect? You my have a redirect loop.

Comment: I call the method redirect normally @tigrang . Controller are differente btw I don't think is a loop

Comment: You probably won't get any good answers here, as all people can do is shooting in the dark. You'll have to debug this further on your own first, like checking your browsers network console to see what exactly happens, and using something like Xdebug to profile your appplication in order to figure if and where exactly the time is spent.

Comment: I have only ask how to reference right a controller into a component, not to solve other problem :) @ndm

Comment: You already _are_ referencing it correctly, hence these comments.

Comment: perfect so my loop is another problem I think @ndm